# Does CentOS - 7.1 to 7.8 are end of life(EOL) OS?

Tags: linux, centos, security

In the official CentOS wiki https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product

Mentioned full update ends by Q4-2020 and Maintenance updates EOL is 30-06-24. I can't find patch(Sub release) wise EOL information. Does it means all sub-releases except latest are end of life?

Comment: CentOS is moving to CentOS Stream. It's time to move away from using CentOS in production. You can use a search engine, but [this is a good starting link](https://itsfoss.com/centos-stream-fiasco/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CentOS [FAQ 29](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#How_does_CentOS_versioning_work.3F) addresses this directly:

> The CentOS Project provides updates or other changes ONLY for the latest version of each major branch. [...] Older minor versions are not supported in official support avenues.

The bottom line is that if 7.9 is the current subrelease for CentOS 7, then running 7.6 means you are not up to date with security patches, etc. UNLESS you have arranged for those security patches to be backported yourself

Comment: To tell it otherwise, contrary to RHEL, CentOS has no notion of security-only updates. The flag to do only security updates has no effect and won't update anything. As confirmed in this CentOS forum by a CentOS team member: https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=59369 . Security team might not even be aware of that.

Comment: @A.B is that still true for CentOS 7? (I don't run CentOS on a regular basis.)

Comment: (edited comment): That comment was indeed about CentOS6, but that is the same for CentOS7. I was unaware of this and discovered it when finding that CentOS7 didn't follow RHEL7 in automatic updates (which were set as security only). I had to tell it to Security which wasn't aware of it. Only EPEL (which is common between RHEL and CentOS) gets the security tags, wrote it to other people unaware at SF: https://serverfault.com/questions/996189/update-centos-security-patches/996195#996195

Comment: For example CentOS-7.9 is latest release in 7 series, then other versions- 7.8, 7.7, 7.4 etc... previous version are EOL?

Comment: @Kishore What does it matter if they are EOL. They don't receive security patches, bug fixes, updates, etc. That's enough to let you know that you need to keep the system up to date with the latest releases.

Comment: @Kishore yes they are EOL because they are no longer supported

Comment: Okay thanks a lot Nasir Riley and Roaima.